# ¿Por qué no puedo eliminar satisfactoriamente un usuario Firebase desde Android?

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy tratando de escribir un método que al lanzarlo desde un botón en mi Activity elimine el usuario que inicialmente se logueó en mi aplicación usando los providers de Firebase, pero estoy experimentando dos problemas. Vale mencionar que la pantalla de logueo la estoy trabajando con Firebase-UI

Primero aquí les muestro el método:

```
private void deleteAccount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ingreso a deleteAccount");
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG,"OK! Works fine!");
                startActivity(new Intent(Main3WelcomeActivity.this, Main3Activity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG,"Something is wrong!");
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Ocurrio un error durante la eliminación del usuario", e);
        }
    });
}
```

1) El primer problema se presenta al ejecutar el método anterior. Parece que efectivamente va a proceder todo bien pero un mensaje de Smart Lock aparece y el usuario aparece logueado de forma automática. Les dejo una captura de pantalla de dicho mensaje. Quizá me falte alguna validación para que se desconecte completamente y de este modo elimine alguna credencial almacenada en Smart Lock, pero no estoy seguro de ello.

[image: Smartlock message]

2) El segundo problema lo tengo cuando ya ha pasado un tiempo de estar logueado el usuario en la aplicación. Al ejecutar la función internamente la aplicación lanza la siguiente excepción:

```
06-30 00:01:26.672 11152-11152/com.devpicon.android.firebasesamples E/Main3WelcomeActivity: Ocurrio un error durante la eliminación del usuario
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN ]
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacq.zzbN(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacn$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy.zzbO(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzact$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Sobre esto último he leído que [Debo re-autenticar al usuario](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo manejar esto considerando que estoy usando Google Sign In a través de Firebase UI.